# The POST request is working, but the GET request is not working

Tags: node.js, express

```
const {flyOrder} = require('../models/flyOrder');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
```

POST request

```
router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    let flyorder = new flyOrder({
        orderNumber: req.body.orderNumber,
        supplier: req.body.supplier,
        courier: req.body.courier,
        submitDate: req.body.submitDate,
        completedDate: req.body.completedDate,
        customerPhoneNumber: req.body.customerPhoneNumber,
        origin: req.body.origin,
        destination: req.body.destination,
    })
    flyorder = await flyorder.save();

    if(!flyorder)
    return res.status(400).send('the order cannot be created!')

    res.send(flyorder);
})
```

GET request

```
router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    //console.log("GET request")
    const orderList = await flyOrder.find();
    if(!orderList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(orderList);
})
```

I try to console log in the beggining of the get function, nothing happened.
I using the postman to test the code, and when i try to get the function not called, but the POST request is working.

Comment: What is the output postman retrieve for the get request?

Comment: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.4d6b576f.js"></script></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>

Comment: Your serving a react app on the same port maybe you have some kind of proxy configuration set on your stack can you attach the server running script and also describe all your running stack?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I define a default get request in another file in the routers:

```
router.get('*', (req,res)=>{...
```

I delete the function and the other get requests now are working.

Answer (score 0):

From the POSTMAN /GET request output

<!doctype html>React AppYou need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

it's look like you running react app at the same port has the express server

You need to verify your not miscunfigure proxy to a web application and also check network configuration in case your running your stack with rocker compose

Comment: Its true, but right now i running just the backend (the react app is not running), and other GET requests in other routers are working.

Comment: Pleas attach package.json file for react and expreass apps

Comment: {
  "name": "eshop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "backend",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  }
}

Comment: {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }

  }
}

Comment: Do you run your app with docker compose? Also please attach root express router code

Comment: const router = express.Router();
const flyOrdersRouter = require('./routers/flyOrders');
app.use(`${api}/flyUsers`, flyUsersRouter)

Also when I change the router.get(..
to router.post(.. . Its works